# Docker healthcheck causes the container to crash

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I have a customized rabbitmq image that I am using with docker-compose (3.7) to launch a docker cluster. This is necessary because of some peculiar issues when trying to deploy a cluster in docker swarm. The image has a shell script which runs on the primary and secondary nodes and makes the modifications needed to run a cluster. This involves stopping rabbitmq and running rabbitmqctl commands to create the cluster between the two nodes. This configuiration works flawlessly until I try to add in a healthcheck. I have tried adding it in to the image and adding it into the compose file. Both cause the image to crash and constantly restart. I have the following shell script which gets copied into the image:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eo pipefail

# A RabbitMQ node is considered healthy if all the below are true:
# * the rabbit app finished booting & it's running
# * there are no alarms
# * there is at least 1 active listener

rabbitmqctl eval '
{ true, rabbit_app_booted_and_running } = { rabbit:is_booted(node()), rabbit_app_booted_and_running },
{ [], no_alarms } = { rabbit:alarms(), no_alarms },
[] /= rabbit_networking:active_listeners(),
rabbitmq_node_is_healthy.
' || exit 1
```

On an already running image this works and produces the correct result.
I tried the flowing in the compose file:

```
     healthcheck:
       interval: 60s 
       timeout: 60s 
       retries: 10 
       start_period: 600s
       test: ["CMD", "docker-healthcheck"]
```

It seems that the `start_period` is completely ignored. I can see the health status with an error right away. I have also tried the following native rabbitmq diagnostics command:

```
rabbitmq-diagnostics -q check_running && rabbitmq-diagnostics -q check_local_alarms
```

This oddly fails with an "unable to find rabbitmq-diagnostics" error, despite the fact the program is definitely in the path. I can execute the command successfully in an already running container.

If I create the container without the healthcheck and then add it in after the fact from the command line with:

```
docker service update --health-cmd docker-healthcheck --health-interval 60s --health-timeout 60s --health-retries 10 [container id]
```

it marks the container healthy. So it works but just not in a start up configuration. It seems like to me that the healthcheck should not begin until 10 minutes have passed. It doesn't seem to matter how long I wait for everything to startup using the `start_period` parameter it still causes the container to fail.
Is this a bug or is there something mysterious about the way `start_period` works?
Anyone else every have this problem?

Comment: Do you have supported versions of docker-compose and docker engine for `start_period` parameter? https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-23?

Comment: Does the healthcheck go successful within the 600s window, and then back to failing (e.g. a start, initialize, restart cycle in an entrypoint)?

Comment: I have the latest version of docker-compose and docker. I started at a much lower setting. It takes about 2 minutes for my rabbitmq scripts to get the cluster setup so I started with 3 minutes. It fails right away and no matter how long I wait never gets to healthy.